# Using Classes In Python

Tags: python, class, instantiation

Im currently undertaking a course from [Dataquest](https://dataquest.io/mission/5) for manipulating data in Python

We have gotten to the point of classes and im trying to wrap my head around them

I have written this code based on NFL data supplied in the tutorial
Im just trying to get the number of wins in the dataset but every time i try to run the method count_total_wins I get the error similiar to below

Im obviously doing something very basic that is incorrect, Can anyone see my error?

**Bound method...Team object at 0x7f3ca0a47160**

## The data is loaded into the nfl variable.

```
class Team():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def count_total_wins(self):
        count = 0
        for row in nfl:
            print (row[2])
            if row[2] == self.name:
                count = count + 1
        return count
```

## My attempt at running the code

```
Team1 = Team ("Denver Broncos")
print (Team1.name)
print (Team1.count_total_wins)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `count_total_wins` is a method, you need to call it by appending `()` after the method name.

```
team1 = Team ("Denver Broncos")
print(team1.name)
print(team1.count_total_wins())
                            ^^
```

Without `()`, it will just print a reference to the method itself.

BTW, [use names that starts with lowercase character for variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

Comment: @jsfan, Thank you for the correction and improvement.

Comment: Thanks guys this is the answer i was looking for. Appreciate the syntax correction as well